# RESTful enums. string or Id?

Tags: web-services, rest, enums, localization

I have a RESTful service that exposes enums.

Should I expose them as localised strings, or plain integers?

My leaning is toward integers for easy conversion at the service end, but in that case the client needs to grab a list of localised strings from somewhere in order to know what the enums mean. Am I just creating extra steps for nothing?

There seems to be little information I can find about which is commonly done in RESTful APIs.

EDIT:

OK. Let's say I'm writing a website that stores information about people's pets. I could have an AnimalType enum

```
0 Dog
1 Cat
2 Rabbit 
etc.
```

When people grab a particular pet resource, say `/pets/1`, I can either provide a meaningful localised string for the animal type, or just provide the ID and force them to do another look up via a `/pets/types` resource.

Or should I provide both?

Answer (score 3):

I guess you should think in therms of consistent RESTful API you want to expose to your clients.

Wheter you yourself use enums in your code or not is an implementation detail. 
Wheter your client will use enums in his implementation you neither know nor should that bother you because that's just different level of abstraction.

API design first, implementation follows.

If you provide a bit more insight of what kind of information you want to return to your client using these enums  I could give more straight answer.

For now I guess if integer ids and string descriptions are relevant in describing information or state you want to return in call to your RESTful resource then you shuould return them both wrapped in a json or xml document.

Comment: I'd say as a response to /pets/{petId} you should provide full information about the the resource so in your case, the localized string and the id.

You could as well provide a collection resource under /pets that would return either a collection of full pet resource representations or just partial representations (maybe pet ids) with urls to individual pet resources (http:// .../pets/{petId}) or just a collection of urls only.

Answer (score 2):

If the intent is for the API consumer to use these values programmatically (i.e. make decisions based on them), I would go with UNlocalized strings (and make sure they are well-documented and stable). Enum values are not localized in local development frameworks and developers are used to dealing with this, not sure why a web API would be any different.

If the intent is for the API consumer to display these values to the user, I would go with localized strings.

If the intent is to be able to do both, I would go with UNlocalized strings (IDs), but consider providing a separate API endpoint/resource (or even an offline document) to map these IDs to localized strings.

And if for some reason you really care about message size (e.g. you have thousands of these things in a single message, and it's a mobile scenario), only then I would *consider* going with numeric IDs.