# Is it a bad design decision to expose an enumeration in web API which is consumed by multiple clients?

Tags: c#, web-services, asp.net-web-api

I am currently developing an restful API (using web api) which is to be consumed by multiple customers. Is it ok to expose enums to the consumers? Such as

```
   public enum StatusType{Open,Closed}
```

Then when client does a call to GetOrder i would return this to them:

```
   public class Order
    {
      public StatusType CurrentStatus{get;set;}
      public int OrderId{get;set;}
    }
```

One of the developers said that this should not be done as we should not expose internal types to the client consumer, and we should instead create a class for this in the form.

```
   public class OrderStatus
    {
     public string Status{get;set;}
     public int Id{get;set;}
    }
```

Then when client does a call to GetOrder i would return this to them:

```
public class Order
{
  public OrderStatus CurrentStatus { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
}
```

Please can you tell me which one I should and why?

thanks
Niall

Comment: possible duplicate of [RESTful enums. string or Id?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878523/restful-enums-string-or-id)

Answer (score 4):

I think that as long as you are not exposing internal mechanisms, such as *other* statuses which the order might be in, such as *Awaiting Manager Approval*, or some other status which your clients can't be bothered with or simply should not know about you should be fine.

Exposing a set of enumerations would, in my opinion, allow your clients to use a standardized way of interacting with your application.